# Can't get specific value in range via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do something very simple, which is to pass a range to a script function in Google Sheets, and have it return the first value in the first row. Here's my function:

```
function totalTake(pRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(pRange)
  const numRows = range.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  return range[0,0]
}
```

I've tried this with the reference 1,1 and it makes no difference. I'm passing in `=totalTake("F4:H74")` in the cell, and there is certainly a string value in the first value. It returns the correct number of rows or columns, so it gets an array, but I suspect it has no values in it. I've tried modifying the `sheet =` assignement to include the current sheet; nothing makes any difference: the returned value is a blank.

What on earth am I missing?

EDIT: it may be misleading to pose the question this way, but it should be treated as "get an arbitrary cell value at a determined location for x and y", not just the first cell in the first row. But after I failed to get it to find values while iterating, leading me to suspect that the range extracted was full of empty values, I reduced it to just finding one cell where the value was known.

To elaborate the question slightly: do these arrays of values use a zero- or one-based array notation? **Answer:** zero based

Comment: The main issue here is **not** how you index `range` which is wrong. The main issue is that you are using the `range` object to get values. Here is a link to familiarize yourself with Google Apps Script: [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of the first row and first column of the range.
- You want to use the script as the custom function.
- When `=totalTake("F4:H74")` is put to a cell, you want to retrieve the value of the cell "F4".

  - From `it return the first value in the first row.`, I understood like this.

In this case, I would like to propose to modify `return range[0,0]` as follows.

#### From:

```
return range[0,0]
```

#### To:

```
return range.getValue();
```

- In this modification, when `=totalTake("F4:H74")` is put to a cell, the value of the cell "F4" is returned.

  - From `it return the first value in the first row.`, I understood like this. If I misunderstood your goal, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

#### Note:

- In your script, it seems that `numRows` and `numCols` are not used. When you want to use, please modify the script.

#### Reference:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

### Added:

From the following replying,

> The actual goal is to get a value at any abtrary x,y location in the range.

I understood like below.

- You want to retrieve a value from the range by giving the coordinate of the range. But in this case, the upper left of the coordinate is `(x, y) = (0, 0)`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return range[0,0]
```

#### To:

```
return range.offset(y, x).getValue();
```

- In this case, please put a custom formula of `=totalTake("F4:H74", 5, 5)`. In this case, the value of cell "K9" is returned.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)

  - For example, when you use this method, you can also retrieve the values by giving the coordinate and length.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. In an effort to keep the question simple, I perhaps oversimplified; see my exchange with Marios. I've clarified the question somewhat. The actual goal is to get a value at any abtrary x,y location in the range.

Comment: @Dan Donaldson Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. From your replying, I added one more modification point. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Tanaike: thanks very much for that answer, it completely opens the door to what I want. I've marked the answer as best and upvoted it.